# Can you set a file to read-only in AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Sometimes, we need to include public source code in one of our Dot Net projects, to build, but we want to prevent our copy of the the public source code from being updated, because those changes will be lost when we upgrade to any newer version of such source code.

(The 15 similar question hits that came up when I typed in this question were not relevant...)

Comment: You can make repo strategy so no one can change main branch with out review and PR

Comment: Or the code you won't change should be moved to a separate repo that only system or admin has access to

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann. I am using TFVC.

Answer (score 1):

TFVC supports folder- and file-level permissions. Please refer to the documentation [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/control-access-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops)[[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/set-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops).

You'll want to define who shouldn't have the ability to modify the folders containing the code, then change their "Check in" permission to "not set".